# Line breaking in bash script

Tags: bash, newline

In my company style guide it says that bash scripts cannot be longer than 80 lines. So I have this gigantic sed substitution over twice as long. How can I break it into more lines so that it still works? I have

```
sed -i s/AAAAA...AAA/BBBBB...BBB/g
```

And I want something like

```
sed -i s/AAAAA...AAA/
BBBBB...BBB/g
```

still having the same effect.

Comment: 80 columns, that's an old legacy requirement...

Comment: @jordanm If you're over 80 columns long in a bash script, 99% of the time you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Swiss - it's very easy to do with pipes to `awk`

Comment: @jordanm You description sounds like it could possibly be cleaned up. Awk is a scripting language, so complicated Awk scripts are better put in their own file as is done with Perl scripts. More importantly, you can break a command with pipes up into multiple lines without even needing to escape the newline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Possible ways to clean up

1) Put your sed script into a file

```
sed -f script [file ...]
```

2) Use Regex shorthand

```
sed 's!A\{30,\}!BBBBB...BBBB!g'
```

3) Use Bash variables to help break it up a bit

```
regex="AAAA.AAAAAA"
replace="BBBB...BBBBBBB"
sed "s/${regex}/${replace}/g"
```

### What not to do

1) Escape the newline to break it up into multiple lines.

You will end up with a newline in your sed script that you don't want.

```
sed 's/THIS IS WRONG /\
AND WILL BREAK YOUR SCRIPT/g'
```

Comment: +1 Yeap, this is the right way; especially with `sed` in the context of scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shell continuation character, which is normally `\`.

```
[~]$ foo \
> and \
> bar
```

Space is not required:

```
[~]$ foo\
> and\
> bar\
> zoo\
> no space\
> whee!\
```

Comment: yes but that requires space to be inserted before it is used. I do not have this luxury with sed substitution :(

Answer (score 1):

Just insert backslash character before a newline:

```
sed -i s/AAAAA...AAA/\
BBBBB...BBB/g
```

Comment: yes but that requires space to be inserted before it is used. I do not have this luxury with sed substitution :(

Comment: Works for me without any spaces.